# Hibernate Falsley Warns Name Parameters Are Not Supported

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I began seeing this warning in my logs:

> HHH000456: Named parameters are used for a callable statement, but database metadata indicates named parameters are not supported.

and it was cause by this line

```
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(RECORD_ID, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
```

Diving into the Hibernate implementation show the line that logs the warning

```
private void prepareForNamedParameters() {
    if (this.parameterStrategy == ParameterStrategy.POSITIONAL) {
        throw new QueryException("Cannot mix named and positional parameters");
    } else {
        if (this.parameterStrategy == ParameterStrategy.UNKNOWN) {
            ExtractedDatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = ((JdbcEnvironment)this.getSession().getJdbcCoordinator().getJdbcSessionOwner().getJdbcSessionContext().getServiceRegistry().getService(JdbcEnvironment.class)).getExtractedDatabaseMetaData();
            if (!databaseMetaData.supportsNamedParameters()) { // true, :picard-facepalm:
                LOG.unsupportedNamedParameters();
            }

            this.parameterStrategy = ParameterStrategy.NAMED;
        }

    }
}
```

So I did some investigating, which yielded:

```
SessionImplementor sessionImp = (org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementorSessionImplementor) entityManager.getDelegate();
DatabaseMetaData metadata = sessionImp.connection().getMetaData();        
metadata.supportsNamedParameters();  // true
```

which is confusing.

Thoughts?  What am I missing?  We have a 2016 MySQL db.

Comment: This is more of a question. Are you sure Mysql supports named parameters for procedure calls? This case is still open -
 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73991

Comment: @Sashi thats interesting.  I can use named parameters in a straight sql query, so that is news to me that is would not be supported and adds to my confusion.